# Display problems when running ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 9570

Tags: dell

I have just recently got myself a Dell XPS 9570. I have had no end of trouble trying to get this to work with any flavour of linux.
Ubuntu 18.04 seems to get me the furthest.

The only problem I'm facing now is that after about 20mins of use the screen dies with random lines of colour drawn all over making the screen unusable.

I have installed the absolute latest drivers from Nvidia 396.24 (which helped, it was breaking at login before).

Is this just a driver issue or is there some other configuration/setting I can tweak.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem with your monitor, possibly power supply problem.

Comment: @waltinator, no, it is looks like it is not. I was able to fix it by upgrading kernel, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just got mine and had the same issue.

The solution to random color lines is to upgrade to the newest kernel, it is very easy [using Ukuu](https://www.wikihow.com/Update-Ubuntu-Kernel).

Also install [latest nVidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers).

This didn't solve ALL the problems I have so far but I am still working on it...
Other problems I have related to nVidia video card:

- Fans making noise
- Does not wake up from sleep mode
- Slow UI rendering (you can see it even when you move windows across the screen)

I know that these are related to nVidia video card because as I switch to Intel video card they are gone. You can try that by issuing this command: `sudo prime-select intel`, if you want to switch back - `sudo prime-select nvidia`. This requires reboot.

Good luck.

Comment: Because answer can be around for a long time instead of saying "Install to latest kernel" say what worked for you, ie `4.18.3`. Due to regression bugs someone might find `4.18.4` is the latest, install it, it won't work, and assume the answer is wrong. Armed with knowledge `4.18.3` works they could try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I updated and have been running 4.18.3 with no issue for a few weeks now. See steps to update kernel here https://medium.com/@pwaterz/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-18-04-on-the-15-inch-dell-xps-9570-with-nvidia-1050ti-gpu-4b9a2901493d.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue on a Dell precison 5520 where it would show random colored lines all over the screen. It started gradually after some time of being booted up like you mentioned but after a few days I saw the same lines in the POST boot screen and I figured it was a hardware problem.
See if you can repro on windows (if you still have dual boot). The problem seems to be due to temperature in the motherboard which ended up being replaced by a dell technician.

Answer (score 0):

Got mine 5 days ago. Since then no issues (I use it as my main PC).

I used the following script after the installation and everything (except the fingerprint) works without issues. No kernel update is required in my case.

https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin/blob/master/xps-tweaks.sh